# failed to run unit test for component that extends a base class in angular

Tags: angular, angular-unit-test

I am trying to write unit test for a component that extends a base class.

**component.ts**

```
   export class DesktopPresentationAreaComponent extends AbstractPresentationComponent {
            constructor() {
                super(store, webcast);
            }
   }
```

**base class**

```
export abstract class AbstractPresentationComponent {
    constructor(protected store: MainStorageService,
                protected webcast: WebcastService) {
        this.store.get('state').subscribe();
    }
```

when I run 'ng test' it shows following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined in AbstractPresentationComponent
```

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the 'MainStorageService' instance. Then spyOn for 'store.get('state')'. For e.g.

Get service instance

```
store = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MainStorageService);
```

Spying on get method

```
spyOn(store, 'get').and.callFake(() => {
    return Observable.from([]);
})
```

Comment: I tried but it throws same error.it is failed to mock the methods in base class.Is there any way to mock the base class in the component?

Comment: Post your component and test file code you have tried with